# Cassandra Counter column in realtime statistic

Tags: java, statistics, cassandra, hector

I want to construct a program do the statistic page view base on Cassandra 
i know that if we use counter column can do that.  But i have  a trouble that the Counter column can work not righ if we have many client to try to update it. (this make this value of counter is wrong )

I 'm reading `Cage` , but i wonder that : is there other solution for this problem ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter columns should work even if you have many clients updating them, there should be no need for locking.

Take a look at [coutandra](http://countandra.org/) if you are doing stats with cassandra.